# Excel array (2 variables)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I have the following sheet https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ai6fM6lT5gt6h00EUCmpnuwlgNtr

It consists of table 1 that is populated by a list (with an array).

Goal: I want to populate a second table based on the value in B21 and based on the last column of the table:

1. When there is only the value "red" in last column of the table: copy table 1 to table 2 (value of B21 doesn't matter)
2. When there is a mix of the values "red" and "green": filter based on the value of B21

Any help is greatly appreciated! See the sheet for the possible scenarios and the desired outcome.

Comment: Whole exercise needs Single Variable Array Formula instead of Two, since your expected output in Table 2 has Uni-color either Red or Green !!

Comment: Scenario 3 and 4 only needs Array Formula to extract either Red or Green.

Comment: @RajeshS I need a single formula for all 4 scenarios. Could you try to test it in my sheet? You can edit the sheet so I can see the result.

Comment: Okay @A. Hond let me try the Formula ☺

Comment: If only contain Green and B21 is Red, did the result return green list?

Comment: @RajeshS Table 1 will never contain only green. There are 2 possibilities: all red or a mix of red and green. See the scenarios and the expected outcome. There are no more scenarios

Comment: @A.Hond, check Sheet2 I've written Formula. You press F2 & finish with Ctrl+Shift+Enter you get Green Row. Next time enter Red, you get Rows have Red. I've tried but may be is on Cloud so that not accepting Array Formula.

Comment: @RajeshS I don't understand what you did. If you just enter your formulas in C26 - F26, then I will turn them into an array (Ctrl-Shift-Enter)

Comment: The link doesn't work

Comment: Check this one,, https://www.dropbox.com/s/4zxjk6wezbas9su/Array%20%281%29.xlsm?dl=0   and from Tab Click Sheet2 ☺

Comment: scenario1 is not working. see https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ai6fM6lT5gt6h0-Cyysq59Giy1NN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it myself!

The formula is:
=IFERROR(IF($C$23=0;INDEX($C$3:$C$12; SMALL(IF($F$3:$F$12="red";ROW($F$3:$F$12)-ROW($F$3)+1);ROWS($F$3:$F3)));INDEX($C$3:$C$12; SMALL(IF($F$3:$F$12=$B$21;ROW($F$3:$F$12)-ROW($F$3)+1);ROWS($F$3:$F3))));"")

https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ai6fM6lT5gt6h0-Cyysq59Giy1NN